# R: How to get a sum of two distributions?

Tags: r, sum, distribution

I have a simple question.
I would like to sum of two non-parametric distributions.

Here is an example.
There are two cities which have 10 houses. we know energy consumption for each house. (edited) I want to get the probability distribution of the sum of a random house chosen from each city.

```
A1 <- c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7) #10 houses' energy consumption for city A
B1 <- c(11,13,15,17,17,18,18,19,20,22) #10 houses' energy consumption for city B
```

I have a probability distribution of A1 and B1, how can I get the probability distribution of A1+B1? 
If I just use `A1+B1` in R, it gives `12 15 18 20 20 22 22 24 26 29`. However, I don't think this is right. Becuase there is not order in houses.

When I change the order of houses, it gives another results.

```
# Original
A1 <- c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7)
B1 <- c(11,13,15,17,17,18,18,19,20,22)
#change order 1
A2 <- c(7,6,5,4,4,3,3,3,2,1) 
B2 <- c(22,20,19,18,18,17,17,15,13,11)
#change order 2
A3 <- c(3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,1,2) 
B3 <- c(17,17,18,18,19,13,20,11,22,15)
sum1 <- A1+B1; sum1
sum2 <- A1+B2; sum2
sum3 <- A3+B3; sum3
```

[image]

Red lines are sum1, sum2, and sum3. I am not sure how can I get the distribution of the sum of two distributions.Please give me any ideas.Thanks!

(If those distributions are normal or uniform distributions, I could get the sum of distribution easily, but these are not a normal and there is no order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
rowSums(expand.grid(A1, B1))
```

Using `expand.grid` will get you a dataframe of all combinations of A1 and B1, and `rowSums` will add them.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is a good idea! I just wonder if this is right theoretically or statistically. Could you please give me more background information?

Comment: Well it depends on what you want. This is the probability distribution of the sum of a random house chosen from each city. The other answer is also a good answer depending on what exactly you are after.

Comment: "This is the probability distribution of the sum of a random house chosen from each city" This is what I want! ;) Thank you!

Comment: One more question, in this case, there are only 10 houses for each building. so. we need 10 * 10 of combination to derive the distribution. However, if the number of houses is increased, let's say 10,000, it will need 10,000 * 10,000 which could be a burden for simulation. Do you have idea to reduce it? Do you think I should use sampling method?

Comment: @jeremycg I provided an edit to my answer based off what I think yours is doing, and what the OP wants. You think that's the same basic idea?

Answer (score 6):

In theory, the sum distribution of two random variables is the convolution of their PDFs, [details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions),  as:

> PDF(Z) = PDF(Y) * PDF(X)

So, I think this case can be computed by `convolution`.

```
# your data
A1 <- c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7) #10 houses' energy consumption for city A
B1 <- c(11,13,15,17,17,18,18,19,20,22) #10 houses' energy consumption for city B

# compute PDF/CDF
PDF_A1 <- table(A1)/length(A1)
CDF_A1 <- cumsum(PDF_A1)

PDF_B1 <- table(B1)/length(B1)
CDF_B1 <- cumsum(PDF_B1)

# compute the sum distribution 
PDF_C1 <- convolve(PDF_B1, PDF_A1, type = "open")

# plotting
plot(PDF_C1, type="l", axe=F, main="PDF of A1+B1")
box()
axis(2)
# FIXME: is my understand for X correct?
axis(1, at=seq(1:14), labels=(c(names(PDF_A1)[-1],names(PDF_B1))))
```

[image]

Note:

> CDF: cumulative distribution function
>
> PDF: probability density function

```
## To make the x-values correspond to actually sums, consider
## compute PDF
## pad zeros in probability vectors to convolve
r <- range(c(A1, B1))
pdfA <- pdfB <- vector('numeric', diff(r)+1L)
PDF_A1 <- table(A1)/length(A1)                        # same as what you have done
PDF_B1 <- table(B1)/length(B1)
pdfA[as.numeric(names(PDF_A1))] <- as.vector(PDF_A1)  # fill the values
pdfB[as.numeric(names(PDF_B1))] <- as.vector(PDF_B1)

## compute the convolution and plot
res <- convolve(pdfA, rev(pdfB), type = "open")
plot(res, type="h", xlab='Sum', ylab='')
```

[image]

```
## In this simple case (with discrete distribution) you can compare
## to previous solution
tst <- rowSums(expand.grid(A1, B1))
plot(table(tst) / sum(as.vector(table(tst))), type='h')
```

[image]

Comment: I hate to say it, but I didn't know about convolutions previously. I've been reading up, but having trouble fully grasping, particularly with respect to the different `type` arguments available in R. Do you have a link to a favorite explanation? I already read your Wikipedia link, as well as the Wiki on convolutions, and a few other searchers. Anything else appreciated.

Comment: @slickrickulicious thanks for editing and solutions. Also very good study materials:)

Comment: Thanks to both of you; @slickrickulicious After reading some more, I thought that `convolve` could be used to perform a sort of spatial smoothing on a 2D grid by making the second argument representative of a 'kernel'. I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Is that a potentially appropriate use of the function? If so, I might ask another question on here showing my attempt and desired result.

Comment: @rbatt, A very good [blog](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-Understanding-Convolutions/) for convolutions.

Comment: Thank you very much! slickrickulicious, rbatt, and Patric. I think this is the right answer of my question. Could I ask one more thing?  Is it possible to get variables of A1+B1 using deconvolve or something? e.g. (12,13,14,14,...,21,21,21,21,21,....28,29)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

Now that I better understand the question, and see @jeremycg 's answer, I think I have a different approach that I think will scale better with sample size.

Rather than relying on the values in `A1` and `B1` being the only values in the distribution, we could infer that those are simply samples from a distribution. To avoid imposing a particular form on the distribution, I'll use an empirical 'equivalent': the sample density. If we use the `density` function, we can infer the relative probabilities of sampling a continuous range of household energy uses from either town. We can randomly draw an arbitrary number of energies (with replacement), from the `density()$x` values, where the `sample`'s we take are weighted with `prob=density()$y` ... i.e., peaks in the density plot are at x-values that should be resample more often.

As a heuristic, an oversimplified statement could say that `mean(A1)` is 3.8, and `mean(B1)` is 17, so the sum of energy uses from the two cities should be, on average, ~20.8. Using this as the "does it make sense test"/ heuristic, I think the following approach aligns with the type of result you want.

```
sample_sum <- function(A, B, n, ...){
    qss <- function(X, n, ...){
        r_X <- range(X)
        dens_X <- density(X, ...)
        sample(dens_X$x, size=n, prob=dens_X$y, replace=TRUE)
    }

    sample_A <- qss(A, n=n, ...)
    sample_B <- qss(B, n=n, ...)

    sample_A + sample_B
}

ss <- sample_sum(A1, B1, n=100, from=0)

png("~/Desktop/answer.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", res=150)
plot(density(ss))
dev.off()
```

Note that I bounded the density plot at 0, because I'm assuming you don't want to infer negative energies. I see that the peak in the resultant density is just above 20, so 'it makes sense'.

The potential advantage here is that you don't need to look at every possible combination of energies from the houses in the two cities to understand the distribution of summed energy uses. If you can define the distribution of both, you can define the distribution of paired sums.

Finally, the computation time is trivial, especially compared the approach finding all combinations. E.g., with 10 million houses in each city, if I try to do the `expand.grid` approach I get a `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 372529.0 Gb` error, whereas the `sample_sum` approach takes 0.12 seconds.

Of course, if the answer doesn't help you, the speed is worthless ;)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry my question was not much clear. I want to draw a distribution for a sum of energy for two cities rather than just combing two cities.

Comment: @user3309420 When you say "sum", are you talking about pairing houses from each city, and adding their usage together? This doesn't make any sense to me, statistically; at least not for any scenario that I can imagine. I'm starting to wonder if this is more of a statistical question.

Comment: I changed my question to make it clearer.  My intent was that sum of the pair of houses from each city. That is the probability distribution of the sum of a random house chosen from each city. (I have a probability distribution of A and B, how can I get the probability distribution of A+B?)

Comment: Thank for your effort! This is very helpful!

Comment: Simply awesome, for scalability. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it not the case that sorting the distribution prior to adding solves this problem?

```
A1 <- c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7) #10 houses' energy consumption for city A
B1 <- c(11,13,15,17,17,18,18,19,20,22) #10 houses' energy consumption for city B
sort(A1)+sort(B1)
```

Comment: No.  What the questioner is asking is for the distribution of the sum of a random element from A plus a random one from B.  As demonstrated empirically above, for small samples this can be approximated by considering all possible pairs (which does not scale for large samples).  What you are doing is adding the values pairwise, which is both incorrect (since you're only considering one pair per point), but also, even if it were correct, assumes the samples are of equal size, which is not generally true.