# Sum of multiple distributions

Tags: python, r, convolution, probability-density

**Background**

I try to estimate the potential energy supply within a geographical area using spatially explicit data. For this purpose, I build a Bayesian network (HydeNet package) and attached it to a raster stack in R. The Bayesian network model reads the input data (e.g resource supply, conversion efficiency) of each cell location from the raster stack and computes the corresponding energy supply (MCMC simulations). As a result I obtain a new raste layer with a specific probability distribution of the expected energy supply for each raster cell.

However, I am equally interested in the total energy supply within the study area. That means I need to aggregate (sum) the potential supply of all the raster cells in order to get the overall supply potential within the area.

[Click here for visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cWoK.png)

**Research**

The mathematical operation I want to do is called *convolution*. R provides a corresponding function called *convolve* that makes use of the *Fast Fourrier Transfomration*.

The examples I found so far (e.g. example [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167607/r-how-to-get-a-sum-of-two-distributions), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41251/how-to-produce-a-vector-based-on-two-probability-distributions/41255#41255)) were limited to the addition of two distributions at a time. However, I would like to sum-up multiple distributions (thousands, millions).

**Question**

*How can I sum-up (convolve) multiple probabilty distributions?*

I have up to 18,000,000 probability distributions. Thus the computation efficiency will certainly be an big issue.
Further, I am mainly interested in a solution in R, but other solutions (notably Python) are appreciated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if convolving multiple distributions at once would result in a speed increase. Wouldn't somthing like `a123 = convolve(a1, a2, a3)` behind the scenes  simplify to `a12 = convolve(a1, a2); a123 = convolve(a12, a30)`?. Regardless, in R what you could try is using the `foreach` package and do all convolutions in parallel. on a quad core that would speed up the calculations (theoretically) by a factor 4. If you really want more speed you could try to use the `OpenCL` package to see if you can do these calculations parallel on a GPU, but this is programmingwise not easy to get into. If I were you I would focus more on these kind of solutions than trying to speed up functions that do convolutions.