# Sum PDFs within list using convolve or similar and plot a unique PDF

Tags: r, list, pdf, plot

Starting from [R: How to get a sum of two distributions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167607/r-how-to-get-a-sum-of-two-distributions)

Here an example of my data:

```
#create vectors
A1 <- c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7) 
B1 <- c(11,13,15,17,17,18,18,19,20,22) 
C1 <- c(2,2,4,4,6,7,9,10,10,11,11,11,22)

#create list
lst = list(A1, B1, C1)

#compute PDF
pdf_lst = lapply(lst, function(u) table(u) / length(u))
```

How can I sum these 3 PDFs in order to plot a unique PDF distribution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to sum the tables by their names and then divide by the total number of tables. If this is true, you can get most of the way with `tapply`:

```
temp <- tapply(unlist(pdf_lst), names(unlist(pdf_lst)), FUN=sum) / length(pdf_lst)
```

temp

```
         1         10         11         13         15         17         18    ....
0.03333333 0.05128205 0.11025641 0.03333333 0.03333333 0.06666667 0.06666667    ....
```

This is sorted alphbetically, so 1 is next to 10. To sort according to the numeric value, use `as.numeric` and `order`:

```
temp <- temp[order(as.numeric(names(temp)))]
```