# How to calculate x-values of the convolution of two distributions?

Tags: r, statistics, convolution

(This question may be suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/, but I'm thinking it's just how you calculate what I want in `R` that is my question).

I'm trying to add multiple distributions together, and then look at the resulting distribution.  I'll illustrate my problem with a simple example using normally distributed random variables, `p1` and `p2`.

```
set.seed(21)
N <- 1000

p1 <- rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 1)
p2 <- rnorm(N, mean = 10, sd = 1)
```

Which we can plot:

```
data.frame(p1, p2) %>%
  gather(key="dist", value="value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, color=dist)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

I can add these distributions together using `convolve`. Okay so that's fine. But what I can't figure out, is how to plot the summation of the distributions with the appropriate x-values. In the examples I've seen, it looks like the x-values are manually added in a way that doesn't seem "accurate" for lack of better work. See this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167607/r-how-to-get-a-sum-of-two-distributions).

I can "add" them together and plot:

```
pdf.c <- convolve(pdf1.y, pdf2.y, type = "open")

plot(pdf.c, type="l")
```

[image]

**My question is how to get the corresponding x-values of the new distribution. I'm sure I'm missing something from a foundational statistics point of view.**

Appendix for `pdf1` and `pdf2`:

```
set.seed(21)
N <- 1000

p1 <- rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 1)
p2 <- rnorm(N, mean = 10, sd = 1)

pdf1.x <- density(p1)$x
pdf2.x <- density(p2)$x

pdf1.y <- density(p1)$y / sum(density(p1)$y)
pdf2.y <- density(p2)$y / sum(density(p2)$y)

df1 <- data.frame(pdf.x = pdf1.x, pdf.y = pdf1.y, dist = "1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(pdf.x = pdf2.x, pdf.y = pdf2.y, dist = "2", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that p1 and p2 are discretized uniformly, with the same interval dx between successive x values. (I see that you have discretized p1 and p2 at random points -- that's not the same, and, without thinking about it some more, I don't have an answer for that.) Let x1 = x1_0 + (k - 1) times dx, k = 1, 2, 3, ..., n1 be the points at which p1 is discretized, and x2 = x2_0 + (k - 1) times dx, k = 1, 2, 3, ..., n2 be the points at which p2 is discretized.

Each point xi_k = xi_0 + (k - 1) times dx represents the center point of a bar which has width dx and height pi(xi_k), i = 1, 2. Thus the mass of the bar is dx times pi(xi_k), and the total mass for all bars approaches 1 as dx approaches 0. These masses are the values which are convolved. If the discretized masses are normalized to 1, then their convolution will also be normalized to 1.

To be very careful, the range over which the distributions are discretized are xi_0 - dx/2 to xi_0 + (ni - 1) times dx + dx/2. After computing the convolution, the range for the result is likewise -dx/2 and +dx/2 the first and last points, respectively.

The convolution has n = n1 + n2 - 1 points, namely x1_0 + x2_0 + (k - 1) times dx, k = 1, 2, 3, ..., n1 + n2 - 1. The first point is x1_0 + x2_0 (i.e. first point for p1 plus first point for p2) and the last point is x1_0 + x2_0 + (n1 + n2 - 2) times dx = (x1_0 + (n1 - 1) times dx) + (x2_0 + (n2 - 1) times dx) (i.e. last point for p1 plus last point for p2). From this you can construct x values corresponding to the convolution via the `seq` function or something like that.

Comment: This may work, because in the real application, the points are discretized uniformly. I'm just having some trouble understanding what `k` is. Could you explain `k` and how it differs from `n`?

Comment: k is just the index of the x points, i.e. x = [x[1], x[2], x[3], ..., x[n]] when x is discretized into n points, so k = 1, 2, 3, ..., n. Note that p1 and p2 can be discretized into different numbers of points (n1 and n2 above) but the distance between successive points (i.e. dx) must be the same.