# How to produce a vector based on two probability distributions?

Tags: r, convolution

Let's assume we have 3 distributions for different types of damage within an insurance company. A weibull distribution with these parameters

```
weibull.data<-rweibull(2000,1,2000)
```

A lognormal one with these parameters

```
lnormal.data<-rlnorm(10000,7,0.09)
```

and at least a frechet distribution for the extreme values looking like these

```
frechet.data<-rfrechet(15, loc=6, scale=1200000, shape=10000)
```

For each of them, I calculated the ruin probability. Now I want to estimate the ruin probability of the convolution of the 3 distributions. But I don't know how to "combine" in a logical way. The vector that I need is a combination of the 3.
Excuse my English, I'm a French native speaker :-)

Comment: I suspect this is more of a statistics question (off-topic here) than a programming question but I admit that I don't understand what you are actually asking. No doubt, that's because of my missing background in the insurance business.

Comment: This is not my industry either, but did you check out answers such as this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167607/r-how-to-get-a-sum-of-two-distributions

Comment: Thanks Roland, thanks Vlad C. for your quick reactions. It's not really about insurance but more about R and stochastic.
Let's say i want to "mix" 3 data set of random variables with the characteristics mentioned above.

Comment: What does "mix" mean here? Do you want to generate random values? Calculate probabilities or quantiles? Something else? I still don't see a programming question.

Comment: Yes you're right Roland ! it's not that much a programming question but it's more a mathematical question or to know which function, i should use in order to make out of the 3 random variables data set a unique data set

Comment: i want to sum up his three continuous random variables this way:
http://statweb.stanford.edu/~susan/courses/s116/node114.html